# Will just installing this package speed up R?

Tags: r

According to [this link](http://statcomputingucdavis.github.com/Spring12BBSeminar/Config_BLAS.pdf)
only installing the following package in Ubuntu will speed up R significantly *for certain calculations*:

```
libatlas3gf-base
```

Do I have to compile from source to get this benefit? If not, do I have to reinstall `R` after installing this package?

Are there any other packages that are similar to this in that they can speed things up by just installing them?

Comment: I was not aware of the package for ubuntu, but I confirm that the ATLAS library will make some operations (including matrix multiplication) a lot faster. I've done it on Windows by overwriting the bin\Rblas.dll with one from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ATLAS/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `libatlas3gf-base` base package will already help over the default "reference blas", but you can (if you care) do better by locally building Atlas. That is in a way the whole point of Atlas as the A and T stand for Automatically Tuned.

Now, keep in mind that a) rebuilding the package is not as trivial as just installing the base package and b) you were quite right in pointing to *certain calculations*.  Your net time spent in R will only rarely by bound by the linear algebra operations that you can accelerate here.  So for me, just installing atlas-base is usually good enough on my Ubuntu and Debian systems.

Comment: thanks, as always. Are there any other packages that can speed things up by just installing them?

Comment: also, how do I check that R is correctly using libatlas after installing the package?

Comment: Atlas and the other blas are transparent; they all just plug un and Debian/Ubuntu takes care of the rest. Just invert a matrix or do another linear algebra ops. Without proper blas R wouldn't even start...